# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Capture or be notified when an sql handle is ran

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'd like to monitor a particular SQL handle and find out who (process id) is running the SQL.

Is there a way to retrieve either a list of proc ids who executed the SQL handle in last N minutes or be automatically notified when that query is ran? or is only option is to run sys.dm_exec_requests continuously?

Comment: what does "a particular SQL handle" mean? a specific query?

Comment: @jyao - *typically*, in SQL Server, that would be a [batch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sql-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2008 R2 or earlier, I'd recommend running a SQL Server Profiler session against the server.

On the General tab, in the template dropdown, select "Blank", then on the Events Selection tab, choose "SQL_StmtStarting" from the list of events.  Click the "Column Filters" button, and fill it out similar to this:

[image]

When you run this profiler session, the results will only show you rows where the `TextData` column contains the text you entered.  Alternately, if you have a sql handle you specifically want to track you can enter that in the filter under `SqlHandle` instead of `TextData`.

On SQL Server 2012 and above, I'd recommend using Extended Events to do this, however that is out of the scope of this question.